# SparkFun Monster Moto Shield current sensing issue

Tags: sensors, current

I am using [a SparkFun Monster Moto Shield (PDF)](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Shields/MonsterMoto-Shield-v12.pdf) for driving two DC motors. The shield is working fine and I am able to drive the motor in both directions. However, the current sensing is continuously showing "zero" in the serial monitor.

I am confused why the shield is not measuring any current. I want to measure normal current of 750 mA and stall current of 6 A but I'm getting zero value continuously. If anyone can help me I shall be very thankful.

Comment: What is supposed to measure the current?

Comment: You're goign to need to post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us how your code is looking like? Please remember that you can not measure current directly, the method that is used to do that is to measure voltage drop on measuring resistor.
Check this image
[image]